# Excel VBA Web Table & Input

Tags: vba, excel, web, yahoo-finance

I've been pretty new to Excel VBA, and I'm at some simple but stumping issues (might be from the overdose of coffee). My code currently pull tables from Yahoo Finance in a loop (so I can put in multiple tickers). What I'm trying to adjust is first inputting the tickers along a row instead of along a column - I tried changing all the "rows" of the lr1 line and that didnt do much. Secondly, I tried to figure out a way to pull the information so it's *only* the numbers, instead of having the entire table pulled out since its the same line items each time. It would help if I could also erase/overwrite my macro results everytime I click the refresh button.

The result would be as simple as putting in a ticker on one column at the top, and the numbers come out right underneath after hitting a button - I feel that I'm close, but no cigar.

This is the code that *works*, not the one riddled with as many mistakes.

```
Sub RefreshQuery()

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim DestinationCell As Range

    Dim StockSymbol As String

    Dim i As Long, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
    lr1 = Range("B:B").Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 1 To QueryTables.Count
        QueryTables(i).Delete
    Next i

    Range("C:D").Clear

    For i = 2 To lr1
        lr2 = Range("D:D").Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set DestinationCell = Cells((lr2 + 3), 4)
        StockSymbol = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells((lr2 + 2), 4).Value = "****" & StockSymbol & "****"
        With QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" & StockSymbol & "+Key+Statistics", Destination:=DestinationCell)
           .Name = "q/ks?s=" & StockSymbol & "+Key+Statistics"
           .FieldNames = True
           .RowNumbers = False
           .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
           .PreserveFormatting = True
           .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
           .BackgroundQuery = True
           .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
           .SavePassword = False
           .SaveData = True
           .AdjustColumnWidth = True
           .RefreshPeriod = 0
           .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
           .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
           .WebTables = "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,25,26,27,29"
           .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
           .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
           .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
           .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
           .WebDisableRedirections = False
           .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

For only the numbers you do a query on another sheet. On your main sheet type `=SheetWithYahooPage!b5` where you want the number only. It's easier to just pull the whole page in.

Queries have their own refresh abilities. Why are you doing it in code? Queries can delete the data. There are two dialogs for Queries. One called Options where you select the page. And another button called Properties on the last dialog where you are asked where to insert the data.